# Post Form Results to Table in Same page

Tags: posts, forms

Is there a way to simply have a form in a page that the user can fill in and on submit continually populate a table directly underneath the the submit button.

This information must also be saved/stored so that when the user comes back the previous posts are there

Im not sure I know how to do what was explained.

This is my form, works fine

```
<form id="myForm" action="" method="post" target="_parent">

<p>Date: 
<input type="date" cf_name="Date" value="" maxlength="25" size="60">


Weight:
<input type="text" cf_name="Weight" value="" maxlength="25" size="60">
</p>

<p>Comments:
<input type="text" cf_name="comments" value="" maxlength="200" size="60">
</p>

<p>Insert Picture (optional):
<input type="text" cf_name="pic1" value="" maxlength="200" size="60">
</p>


<p> 
<input id="submit" type="button" value="Submit" cf_name="submit">
<input type="button" cf_name="cancel" value="Cancel" onClick="closebox()">
</p>
</form>

<table id="details"></table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can have an **ajax** action that sent the data to the **backend** populate the table and return the success or the errors back.

You can use this actions

```
add_action('wp_ajax_*', 'custom_table_insert');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_*', 'custom_table_insert'); // anonymous users
```

This will give you more control and ultimately a far better user experience.
// Ajax Request template

```
jQuery.ajax({
        url : your_settings_object.ajax_url,
        type : 'post',
        data : {
            action : 'wp_ajax_*',
            table_content : table_content
        },
        success : function( response ) {
            alert(response)
        }
    });
```

Note: your_settings_object is a custom object that use to transfer global variables from backend to JS
Also the table_content  is your variable to pass the data and you can take them from the PHP with `$_POST['table_content']`

Comment: Thanks but i'm a noobe at this wp stuff. this is my form so how do I get it done with what you wrote. I was looking for something simple!

Answer (score 0):

Ask the googles about 'how to post to the same page'. Using that information, you will test for a the posting action and then populate the form fields with the posted information.

But with WP, you will also need to create a custom template to do this action. (With a non-WP site, you would just need the code for that page.) You'll need to understand Custom Templates; there are many tutorials about that, one is here http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/how-to-create-a-custom-page-in-wordpress/ ).

A bit of research will help you figure this out. There is not a simple process; but it is an enjoyable learning experience for this geek.